# Question related to the 'bit size' of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

While reading through notes about polynomial factorization ([click here for the content I'm working through](https://www.tankonyvtar.hu/hu/tartalom/tamop425/0046_algorithms_of_informatics_volume1/ch05s05.html)), I'm a little stuck on how to understand the following statement:

> **Corollary 5.75** *The bit size of the irreducible factors in ℚ[x] of an f(x)∈ℤ[x] with leading coefficient 1 is polynomial in the bit size of f(x).*

which follows a proof on Mignotte's bound (the norm involved there is the $2$-norm:

> **Theorem 5.74 (Mignotte)** *Let us assume that the polynomials f(x),g(x)∈ℂ[x] have complex coefficients and leading coefficient 1 and that g(x)|f(x). If deg(g(x))=m, then ∥g(x)∥≤2m∥f(x)∥.*

Now I'm not even sure what the definition for the bit size of a polynomial $f = \sum_i f_i x^i$ is. I didn't find one in the notes linked to.

I reckon it could be something like
$$
(1 + \deg(f)) \lg(||f||_\infty)
$$
or
$$
\sum_{i} lg|f_i|
$$

If it is the first one, I am able to find that the bit size of any irreducible factor $g$ of $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is *bounded* by a polynomial in that of $f$.

Using the well known relationships between the $p$-norms, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 & ||g||_\infty \leq ||g||_2 &\leq 2^{\deg(g)} ||f||_2 \\
 \overset{\text{apply } lg_2}{\implies}
 & lg_2(||g||_\infty) &\leq \deg(g) + lg_2(||f||_\infty) \\
 \overset{\deg(g)\leq\deg(f)}\implies
 & (1 + \deg(g))lg_2(||g||_\infty) &\leq
  (1 + \deg(f))\deg(g) + (1 + \deg(f))\lg_2 ||f||_\infty
\end{eqnarray}
$$

If it is the second definition (which would be more precise), then let
$$
[n]:=\{1,\,\dots,\,n\}
$$
and
$$
f = \prod_{i \in [n]} (x - \alpha_i)
$$
be the complex factorization into linear factors of $f$ and $I \subseteq [n]$ be the set with
$$
g = \prod_{j \in J} (x - \alpha_j)
$$

Then, one should probably consider the following statement:

> Let us express the coefficients of g(x) using its roots:
>   $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> g(x) &= \prod_{i\in I} (x − \alpha_i ) =
>  \sum_{J \subseteq I}\left((-1)^{|J|} \prod_{j \in J}\alpha_j x^{m - |J|} \right) \\
>  &= \sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^{m-i}\left(\sum_{J \subseteq I, |J|=m-i} \prod_{j \in J}\alpha_j\right)x^i
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

which for  $f$ would be
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{n-i}\left(\sum_{J \subseteq [n], |J|=n-i} \prod_{j \in J}\alpha_j\right)x^i
$$

but how would one proceed, or is this even what was meant?

I would be glad if somebody could shed some light on the corollary I quoted/the definition of 'bit size' that is probably applied here and maybe tell me where I'm completely off track/ help me to make sense of this.

EDIT:
Further ahead in the notes linked to, $n\lg||f|| = n\lg||f||_2$ seems to be referred to as the bit size of $f$:

> **Corollary 5.77** *If $f(x) \in ℤ[x]$ is a square-free polynomial with degree $n$, then there is a prime $p=O((n\lg n+2n \lg ||f||)^2)$ (that is, the absolute value of $p$ is polynomial in the bit size of $f$) such that the polynomial $f(x)( mod p)$ is square-free in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.*

This seems unintuitive to me.
However, since $||f||_2 \leq \sqrt {\deg f + 1} ||f||_\infty$, we have
$$
(\deg f + 1) lg||f||_2 \leq (\deg f + 1)\lg\sqrt {n + 1} + (\deg f + 1) \lg ||f||_\infty
$$
which I find more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the definition as a comment after another definition, namely
**Definition 5.72**:

> **Definition 5.72** *The norm of a polynomial* $f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ *with complex coefficients is the real number* $||f(x)||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n|ai|^2}$.
>
> The inequality $max_{i=0}^n|a_i|\leq||f(x)||$ implies that a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients can be described using $O(n\lg||f(x)||)$ bits.